# Can docker services only be attached to docker overlay networks?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network

Right now it seems that docker services can only be attached to docker overlay networks cant be attached to any type of local docker network and it seems as if overlay networks are the only type of non local `swarm` network available. So can docker services only be attached to docker overlay networks or is there any other option available?

My issue is that I am trying to create docker services with containers that will attach themselves to specific routable IP addresses, so that every container will have its own routable IP address.  This is an incredibly difficult thing to achieve with docker overlay networks, which I have still not found a solution too.

Comment: How would you scale up a service if it has a specific IP assigned?

Comment: Just by having a certain number of available ip addresses attached to extra network interfaces of any swarm node machine.  When more containers are desired the containers can be attached to the available extra ip addresses.  So yes scaling is limited, but the purpose of this is to be able to use hardware load balancers for the containers.

Comment: I'd recommend research into "docker service discovery" for you. There are many possible solutions to your underlying problem, and you're attempting to force the tool into an architecture that doesn't fit it's design.

Comment: Yes I think you are probably right, swarm just doesn't seem to be the right tool for the job.  Additionally as far as scaling goes, in the private cloud I am working in, it seems that available IP addresses can be added to my instances from a management node at any time.  So while available IP addresses on any one server might be limited at any one point in time, more can always be added.